# SQL query with case datepart

Tags: sql, case, datepart

I would like to get the data which will exclude weekends from result based on a bind variable value. Somehow I am not able to get this query to run.

```
select *  from tablename a
WHERE a.date >= '2015-04-13'
AND a.date <= '2015-04-21'
AND CASE  WHEN :1 = 'Y' THEN ((DATEPART(dw, a.date) + @@DATEFIRST) % 7) NOT IN (0, 1) END
```

I am getting the following error : **Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'NOT'**.

Comment: Which RDBMS is this for? Please add a tag to specify whether you're using `mysql`, `postgresql`, `sql-server`, `oracle` or `db2` - or something else entirely.

Answer (score 0):

Use a `case` expression here over-complicates things, IMHO. You have two situations:

1. If the bind variables is `Y`, you need to exclude weekends.
2. If it isn't, you want to include them.

This logic can be achieved with a much simpler (again, IMHO) usage of the `or` logical operator:

```
SELECT *
FROM   tablename a
WHERE  a.date >= '2015-04-13' AND 
       a.date <= '2015-04-21' AND
       (:1 != 'Y' OR ((DATEPART(dw, a.date) + @@DATEFIRST) % 7) NOT IN (0, 1))
```